# TSQL DecryptbyKey Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption, subquery

I'm implementing TSQL Encryption on a table I'm using. My SQL isn't too strong, and I have this query currently:

```
SELECT 
    a.salary_group, 
    Count(*) as Count
FROM
    (SELECT
        (CASE
            WHEN Salary BETWEEN 0 and 10000 then '000-010k'
            WHEN Salary BETWEEN 10001 and 20000 then '010-020k'
            ELSE 'Outstanding'
        END) AS 'salary_group'
    FROM 
        Members)a
GROUP BY a.salary_group;
```

This works great. However, I've removed the 'Salary' column from the Members table, and now the data is stored encrypted as a column called 'Salary_Encrypted'.

How can I execute a subquery to
    `SELECT CONVERT(int, DecryptByKey(Salary_Encrypted)) AS 'Salary'` within the above query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
        a.salary_group, 
        Count(*) as Count
    FROM
        (SELECT
            (CASE
                WHEN CONVERT(int, DecryptByKey(Salary_Encrypted)) BETWEEN 0 and 10000 then '000-010k'
                WHEN CONVERT(int, DecryptByKey(Salary_Encrypted)) BETWEEN 10001 and 20000 then '010-020k'
                ELSE 'Outstanding'
            END) AS 'salary_group'
        FROM 
            Members)a
    GROUP BY a.salary_group;
```

Comment: Thanks Akshey! I did use this as an interim solution, but kept trying a few things to try and get a subquery so I wasn't running a convert on each case as the actual query is far longer.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I ended up using:

```
SELECT 
    a.salary_group, 
    Count(*) as Count
FROM
    (SELECT
        (CASE
            WHEN b.Salary BETWEEN 0 and 10000 then '000-010k'
            WHEN b.Salary BETWEEN 10001 and 20000 then '010-020k'
            ELSE 'Outstanding'
        END) AS 'salary_group'
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                Convert(int, dbo.Decrypt(Salary_Encrypted)) AS 'Salary' 
            FROM 
                Members)b
        )a
GROUP BY a.salary_group";
```

I figured this was at least somewhat more optimal than converting each individual line as my actual case statement has far more cases.

Comment: I should probably mention that dbo.Decrypt is a function I found elsewhere.